Retornos de métodos de clases y de funciones
Tenemos la clase siguiente.
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

class GetQuotes:
    def __init__(self, ticker, start_date, end_date):
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.start_date = start_date
        self.end_date = end_date

    def get_quotes(self):
        try:
            # Descarga las cotizaciones del ticker utilizando yfinance
            df_quotes = yf.download(self.ticker, start=self.start_date, end=self.end_date)

            # Selecciona solo la columna 'Close'
            df_close = df_quotes[['Close']]

            # Asegura que las fechas del índice estén en el formato correcto
            df_quotes.index = pd.to_datetime(df_quotes.index).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            df_quotes.index = pd.to_datetime(df_quotes.index)
            df_quotes.index.name = 'Date'

            # Renombrar la columna correctamente
            df_quotes.columns = ['Adj Close', 'Close', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Volume']

            self.historical_closes = df_quotes

            # No need to copy here
            self.close_df = df_quotes[['Close']]
            self.high_low_df = df_quotes[['Close', 'High', 'Low', 'Volume']]

        except Exception as e:
            raise ValueError(f"No se pudieron descargar los datos para {self.ticker} utilizando yfinance: {e}")

        return self.historical_closes, self.close_df, self.high_low_df

# Importar cotizaciones
ticker = '^IBEX'
start_date = '2010-1-1'
end_date = '2024-3-15'

quotes = GetQuotes(ticker, start_date, end_date)
historical_closes, close_df, high_low_df = quotes.get_quotes

# Access historical_closes using object instance
print(quotes.historical_closes)

Al instanciar la clase devuelve el error.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_6986/4281279289.py in <module>
     45 
     46 quotes = GetQuotes(ticker, start_date, end_date)
---> 47 historical_closes, close_df, high_low_df = quotes.get_quotes
     48 
     49 # Access historical_closes using object instance

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable method object

Ha interpretado el resultado como una tupla '[historical_closes, close_df, high_low_df]'
Lo cual me obliga a desempaquetarla haciendo
historical_closes = historical_data[0]
close_df = historical_data[1]
high_low_df = historical_data[2]

Desearía entender por qué no considera que la sentencia 'return self.historical_closes, self.close_df, self.high_low_df' desempaqueta la tupla del resultado y no me devuelve tres DataFrames separados?.

Tienes que cambiar
historical_closes, close_df, high_low_df = quotes.get_quotes

por
historical_closes, close_df, high_low_df = quotes.get_quotes()

Tal como lo escribiste, estás asignando la función (un escalar) en lugar del resultado de la ejecución de dicha función.

Disculpa Moe, pero puedes destacar la diferencia? Yo igual ando aprendiendo py por estos dias, y la verdad que, si no repaso 5 veces las 2 lineas destacadas, no veo la diferencia.

get_quotes es una función, un objeto. get_quotes(), con paréntesis, es la llamada a la función.
